# "Performing a TLS handshake" is very slow (my server/page)

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, server, debian

I have a problem. I use Debian (VPS server) + Apache 2 + Let's Encrypt.

Pages sometimes load very slowly.
The problem is at the stage: "Performing a TLS handshake".

Test at https://www.webpagetest.org

[image]

Test at Chrome addon:

[image]

Server load is 0.00.

I change DNS servers at VPS to OpenDNS - This did not solve the problem.

On the site I'm online only me.

SSH/SFTP works very fine (no communication problems).

The problem I only have with this one (your) page / server. Other SSL sites work well.

The problem I have is not only me - the users also works slowly.

Where can the problem be?

Comment: I am seeing the same problem today on another site.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem, I now getting it.